# How to include Competition Results on Resume

Tags: resume

I just had a question as to how best to integrate competition winnings into a resume. I recently attended the AIAA Design Build Fly competition while also working on the SAE Aerodesign East Competition and received the following awards:

SAE East

- 1st Place Micro Class Overall
- 2nd Place Micro Class Payload Fraction
- 1st Place Advanced Class Overall
- 1st Place Advanced Class Report
- 1st Place Advance Class Hot Award

DBF

- 2nd Place Design Build Fly Overall
- 1st Place Design Build Fly Report

I'm trying to think how to best display my accomplishments without listing them all out but at the same time not diminish my achievements.

Below is a section of my resume where I think it should go. All comments and criticisms appreciated.

[image: resume]

Comment: A few points: If you're using your real name, keep in mind that StackExchange has a high search rank and this could be one of the top results for your name. Awards like this are only valuable additions to your resume if hiring managers will be impressed by them, which typically means that they should have heard of them before. While this site isn't for resume reviewing, the example you give has a few problems and I'd suggest joining [chat] for input once you have the rep for it. You can ping me there with @[username].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these competitions involved significant amounts of work and challenge they merit inclusion on your resume with the amount of detail you give in your example. Conversely, if they weren't that involving you shouldn't dedicate more than one or two phrases to them and you could move it to an Accomplishments or Awards section instead.

In your case the suggested format is good, but as presumably suspect listing all the individual awards is overkill. I'd suggest using something like this:

> **Airplane Design Team Competitions** (AIAA Design Build Fly, SAE Aerodesign East)
>
> - first and second place awards in numerous categories
> - designed airframes and 3D-model prototypes to fit a variety of constraints
> - testing and redesigning to maximize competition score

It's key to highlight that it was a team competition but you want to avoid repeating yourself or mentioning things that are assumed, like the fact that teamwork and communication was involved.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to just make a section called "Honors and Awards" and list it there.

Short but sweet.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because you don't seem to answer the question. OP has a place in mind on his resume but is asking if that's good and how he should list all these awards. Presumably you're not suggesting that he list every one of them on his (one-page) resume.